# How many goalkeepers scored goals in the old First Division?

Tags: football, goalkeeper

As of May 2021, six goalkeepers have scored goals in the English Premier League: Peter Schmeichel, Brad Friedel, Paul Robinson, Tim Howard, Asmir Begovic, and Alisson.

Is there a record of how many goalkeepers scored goals in the old First Division, between its founding in 1888 and the Premier League's founding in 1992?

Comment: When you say scoring a goal, do you mean in open play or do you count penalties ? I suspect this could be a tricky one to answer as you may have a goalkeeper who has also played as an outfield player or vice versa. The [List of goalscoring goalkeeper.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_goalscoring_goalkeepers) gives all the goalkeepers that have scored in proffessional football, it should be able to provide the information.

Comment: Open play, penalties, anything. I did look through that list but there's no information on which competition(s) those goals were scored in; it could have been the Second Division, the FA Cup, etc. I guess I'd have to do that part of the heavy lifting myself.